# Apache Karaf deployment in a Jenkins build pipeline

Tags: apache-karaf

Currently I am trying to improve automation in my test environment which uses Apache Karaf 2.4 and Jenkins.

My goal is, if Jenkins successfully builds the project (and updates a Maven repository), to deploy the new version in Karaf. Karaf and Jenkins run on different machines.

My current solution is to use a feature-descriptor, but I am facing a lot of trouble with it: I found no easy way to update feature-bundles in Karaf 2.4. As far as I know, there is no command that is able to update all bundles of an existing feature in one command.
My current approach is to *grep* the output of the *list* command after a special pattern and find out all BIDs and then run *update*  for all IDs. This approach tends to create bugs (it may include bundles that are not part of the feature when they match the same naming-pattern). And I was wondering if there is a better way to automatically update all my feature bundles in one?

Also, there is another problem: When a new feature gets added or removed from the feature-file, I found no elegant way to update it. My current approach was to first uninstall all associated bundles (with grep again...), then remove the repository from Karaf and then replace the new version of the feature-file in the deployment folder. As this is very circumstantial, I was wondering, if there is a better way to do this in Karaf 2.4?

I think deployment got better in Karaf 3, but I am unable to use it because of this bug [(link)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-1729?jql=project%20%3D%20KARAF%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Critical%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC). As I am in a testing environment and my software tends to be extremely unstable, I often have to kill the Karaf process and restart it again. And this is a big problem in Karaf 3. Hopefully it will be fixed in Karaf 4 but I do not want to wait until it is released.

Do you have any suggestions, how my deployment-process could be improved? Maybe there are better ways than my solution (I really hope so!), but I haven't seen them yet.

Comment: Have You figured out a solution?

Comment: I ended up writing a Python script that did everything (starting/stopping Karaf and copying bundles and the feature-file).

Comment: Can you post an example of the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since I asked this question I switched the company I am working for and the code is somewhere there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice request, cause I've been working on something similar just recently. Basically I've got the same setup you got. 
So you just need to install the latest [Jolokia osgi servlet](http://www.jolokia.org/agent/osgi.html) on top of karaf to make all JMX commands accessible via REST.
For a showcase I created a maven plugin (I'm going to publish those sources in a couple of weeks - might even get into the karaf maven plugin) that installs the current bundle via a rest request on top of Karaf, it's currently also able to check for existing bundles. 
Basically you need to issue the following rest POST:

```
    {
        "type":"EXEC",
        "mbean":"org.apache.karaf:type=bundle,name=root",
        "operation":"install(java.lang.String,boolean)",
        "arguments":["mvn:${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}", true]
    }
```

You'll need to use the latest Jolokia snapshot version to get around the role based authentication which is used in the latest Karaf versions. 
For this you'll also need to create a configuration file in etc, called org.jolokia.osgi.cfg, wich contains the following entries:

```
org.jolokia.user=karaf
org.jolokia.realm=karaf
org.jolokia.authMode=jaas
```

For more details also check the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-3453?jql=project%20%3D%20KARAF%20AND%20created%20%3E%3D%20-4w%20AND%20text%20~%20%22jolokia%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC) for it.

Comment: As I never heard about JMX before, I will have a closer look at it. I already finished a Python-script that does the job, before I read your response. If there is any interest in the script I maybe could provide the code at Github.

Comment: Hi Achim, did you push this plugin ? If so, can you tell us link ? Thanks